# How to prevent form evaluation in lisp macros?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, evaluation, quoting

I'm trying to create a simple memo defun. How can I prevent evaluating of args form in this code?

```
(defmacro defun/memo (name args &rest body)
  `(let ((memo (make-hash-table :test 'equalp)))
     (defun ,name ,args
       (if (gethash (loop for x in ,args collect x) memo)
           (gethash (loop for x in ,args collect x) memo)
           (let ((result (progn ,@body)))
             (setf (gethash (loop for x in ,args collect x) memo) result)
             result)))))
```

Error:

```
; in: DEFUN ADD
;     (X Y)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: X
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     X
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: What's the purpose of that `loop`?

Answer (score 6):

```
(defmacro defun/memo (name args &rest body)
```

You generally declare body with `&body body`, not `&rest body`.

#### Variable capture

```
  `(let ((memo (make-hash-table :test 'equalp)))
```

The `memo` symbol is going to end in the generated code. If `body` contains references to `memo`, for example a symbol that was lexically bound outside of a call to `defun/memo`, then it will use your variable. You should use a fresh symbol instead, generated inside the macro with `gensym` (outside of backquotes). For example, you could do the following to avoid evaluating `expr` twice:

```
(let ((var-expr (gensym)))
  `(let ((,var-expr ,expr))
     (+ ,var-expr ,var-expr)))
```

#### Loop

```
       (if (gethash (loop for x in ,args collect x) memo)
           (gethash (loop for x in ,args collect x) memo)
           (let ((result (progn ,@body)))
             (setf (gethash (loop for x in ,args collect x) memo) result)
             result)))))
```

What is the following supposed to do?

```
(loop for x in ,args collect x)
```

Let's say you define a function with `(defun/memo test (a b c) ...)`, you will inject the literal list of arguments in the above, which will result in code that contains:

```
(loop for x in (a b c) collect x)
```

As you saw, the code is now trying to call function `a` with arguments `b` and `c`.

What if you quoted `args`, in your macro?

```
(loop for x in ',args collect x)
```

Then, you would obtain:

```
(loop for x in '(a b c) collect x)
```

And now, you are just copying a literal list. When the above generated code is run, it will only build a fresh list `(a b c)`. Is that what you need?

What you want is to take all the arguments of your function, i.e. the list of values you were given. The loop could be replaced by:

```
(list ,@args)
```

Which would expand as:

```
(list a b c)
```

And here you have all your values, in a list.

But Common Lisp already provides a way to get all arguments as a list:

```
(defun foo (&rest args) 
  ;; args is bound to a list of values
)
```

Your generated function could do the same.

#### Gethash

Also, `(if (gethash ...) (gethash ...) other)` can be written `(or (gethash ...) other)`. This has the benefits of evaluating the call to `gethash` only once.

*More importantly* (thanks @Sylwester), since you are writing a generic macro, you cannot know in advance if `nil` will be a possible returned value. Having a nil value would make the result recomputed each time, given how the if/or is written. You need to use the secondary return value from `gethash` to check if the element existed:

```
(multiple-value-bind (value exists-p) (gethash ...)
  (if exists-p
      value
      (setf (gethash ...) ...)))
```

Also, if your cached function return multiple values, you may want to grab them all with `multiple-value-list` and returns them with `values-list`.

#### Setf

By the way, the following code:

```
(let ((result expr))
  (setf place result)
  result)
```

... has little reason not to be written as:

```
(setf place expr)
```

The return value of `setf` is required to be the new value. In some cases it could lead to bad style, but here that would be fine.

Comment: Only problem with `(or (gethash ...) (setf (gethash ...) (apply original args)))` is when `nil` is the cached answer it will regenerate the `nil` each time.